# When multiple Chrome profiles are open, how can I choose which browser window links will open in?

Tags: macos, google-chrome, user-profiles

I use two instances of Chrome at the same time - one for my work tasks and one for my personal stuff. Both are signed in as different people ('WorkMe' and 'HomeMe')

If I get a URL sent to me via Skype (or some other non-browser system) and I click it, how can I ensure it opens up in a particular browser window?

On a PC it was quite simple - the last Chrome window that was active is the one that links open in. So I'd just click one Chrome window to make it active and then open the URL. But this doesn't seem to be the case on OSX El Capitan. Links always open in the same browser window regardless of what I've been doing on either one.

**How can I ensure that when I click a link in Skype / Word or wherever that it'll open in the specific browser window that I need?**

For context: It makes a difference because I have multiple profiles, so I will be signed in to different systems on different browsers. For instance if someone Skypes me a link to Twitter about a work-related issue I want to ensure it opens in the browser where I am signed into my work twitter account, not my personal one.

Comment: On OSX, it's whichever you most recently created a new tab in. I'm posting this as a comment because I'm hoping for a better answer.

Comment: @mh. Unfortunately that doesn't seem to be the case in El Capitan, at least not from my test this morning.

Comment: Strange. I've been relying on that behavior heavily. I don't have a non-Sierra machine to test on, but I doubt the behavior has changed between the two releases.

Comment: just to make sure my meaning was clear before: I meant that if you've been browsing in ProfileA but want your next link clicked in SomeApp to open a tab in ProfileB.. you would need to switch to ProfileB, and hit Cmd+T to open a new tab. Then switch back to SomeApp and click. It would then open in ProfileB.

Comment: @mh. I had profile A on screen 1, Profile B on screen 2. I opened a new tab in Profile B and started browsing then opened up a local stored HTML page. It loaded that page in Profile A browser.

Comment: Two variables come to mind, but other than that I'm really not sure: Local files are not strictly opened the same way in OSX as protocol handlers. The separate screens (and/or spaces) could be a factor. If it doesn't work as described when clicking a URL, and you have both browser windows on the same display in the same space, then I'm afraid I'm out of ideas.

Comment: @mh. Yeah, I'm starting to think there are too many variables at play. Which is my primary screen, which browser have I acted with most recently, what window was I using when I opened a new file... I thought it should be simple deduction, but my tests result in out something different each time.

Comment: For Mac users, there is this app which does exactly what you want.

https://hikmetcancelik.com/open-in-profile

Comment: @JonW your question itself solved my problem. I am on a windows machine and didnt know how to manage this. so although it wasn't your intention but thanks

Comment: @CanCelik you should post this as its own answer. It's the only thing that worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

For Mac Users:

There is an app that does exactly what op needs.

https://hikmetcancelik.com/open-in-profile

Disclaimer: I'm the developer of this application.

Comment: I think this *partially* solves it. Although as far as I can tell it forces all links to always open in one specified profile. But sometimes I want a link to open in Profile A and other links to open in Profile B. (i.e. if I get a link sent to a work-related URL I want it opening in my Work profile, but if I get a link to a personal 'fun' URL I want it opening in my Personal one).

Comment: @JonW I completely understand and that's my next update for this tool but haven't got a chance to work on it yet. Will update here once I do though.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a browser picker for this. For example, the free [Velja](https://sindresorhus.com/velja) app (made by me). Velja supports creating rules that enables clicking a link in, for example, Skype, makes it open in a specific Chrome profile.

Answer (score 0):

This app is by far the best browser picker app. It supports Chrome profiles as well as a whole slew of other features. Highly configurable and even supports Apple Handoff when used on multiple computers. I've tried many browser picker apps but this one takes the cake:

https://loshadki.app/openin/

I have no affiliation with the developer. Just a very satisfied customer.

Comment: Thank you for recommending the app! I am developer, it is just my pet project, mostly built it for other reasons, but got a lot of feature requests to support multiple profiles in Chromium browsers, so had to research that.