# When I have two chrome sessions opened, how can I chose in which one links are opened?

Tags: windows-10, google-chrome

I use to work with two Chrome sessions opened for my personal and work accounts, the one personal is basically used to listen to music.

I would like that any links I open, for example for a meeting, to be opened in the work account, but it turns out the links are always opened in the personal account and I have to copy them to the work account session.

Is there some way to control which session is selected by default? I have tried to open first a session with either my personal or work account but that has not had any effect.

NOTE: I have found this other [question](https://superuser.com/questions/1179892/when-multiple-chrome-profiles-are-open-how-can-i-choose-which-browser-window-li) commenting that in Windows the last Chrome window that was active is the one that links open in, but this does not seem to be true to me.

Comment: Try the extension [CopyTabs](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/copytabs/obkbjogekcjalnaebheboejhfkamadkg).

Comment: Thank you harrymc, it has worked.

Comment: I added an answer.

Comment: I am sorry, I worked the first time I used it but it has not worked again.

Comment: I couldn't find any other solution for Chrome.

Comment: What seems to work to me is to open the personal session in Microsoft Edge.

Answer (score 0):

This Chrome extension solved the problem :
[CopyTabs](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/copytabs/obkbjogekcjalnaebheboejhfkamadkg).

> With the CopyTabs Chrome extension, you can open browser URLs from Chrome, into any browser installed on your machine, or any other Chrome profile.

Comment: Edit : It stopped working for the poster.